# Magento 1 :: Adding php to show how much $$ left to spend until they qualify for promo

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to add some php to my order review (step 5) in my one step checkout.

If a customer has < $175 in their GRAND TOTAL, they do not qualify for the deal so we would show the message:

"When you spend $175 USD or more with us, you qualify for our May promotion! You are only "x" USD away!"

BUT

If a customer has > $175 in their GRAND TOTAL the message would say:

"Congratulations! You qualify for our May Promotion!"

**Questions:**

1. I can not seem to find how to call the "grand total" number to be the 
   $second_number?
2. My ELSE does not return the message no matter what the $sum_total is.

**it always returns the same message "When you spend $175 USD or more with us, 
  you qualify for our May promotion! You are only "x" USD away!"

```
<?php

$first_number=175;
$second_number= getTotals;
$sum_total= $second_number - $first_number;
$direct_text = 'When you spend $175 USD or more with us, you qualify for our 
May promotion! You are only';
$direct_text_two = 'away!';
$direct_text_qualify = 'Congratulations! You qualify for our May 
Promotion!';

if ($sum_total < 175){
print ($direct_text.$sum_total.$direct_text_two);
}else {
print ($direct_text_qualify);
}
?>
```

Thanks
Lee

Answer (score 0):

sorry i figured it out.

1. How to call 'Grand Total':

   $quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();
       $quoteData= $quote->getData();
       $grandTotal=$quoteData['grand_total'];
2. Returning the same message no matter the total:
   A: My equation was backwards so I was always returning a negative number.